# How to trigger an onChange event on an input when its value changed by code in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React JS and I am working on a personal project. I am stuck because I could not pass the value of an input field in a child component to the state of the parent component.

I have tried using the onChange event but for some reason the function it is calling, handleChange, is not getting triggered.

Here is a snippet from the Parent component:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        myArray: [{ //myArray is being updated by another child component, which sets the values for id and amount; this works fine
                id: 1,
                amount: 12
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                amount: 23
            }
        ]
        total: 0 //expected value for total is 35
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <Child 
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            myArray={this.state.myArray} />
            )
        }
    }
```

And here is a snippet from the Child component:

```
class Child extends Component {

    render() {
        const { myArray, handleChange } = this.props;

        const totalAmount = myArray.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b.amount;
        }, 0);

        return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="total"> Total Amount: </label>
            <input id="total"
            name="total"
            type="number"
            placeholder="0.00"
            value={totalAmount}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            /> 
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The value in of the total input field renders correctly.
However, what I am trying to achieve is every time this input field value is changed (when the other child component updates the myArray values and therefore the sum also changes), I wish to update the total value in the state of the Parent component.

Comment: Here is a sandbox. Please help :( https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-framework-cu0gb?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to pass field name manually, you can get it from the event. First give your input a name

```
<input name="total" ...etc >
```

Then, you can just receive event in your `handleChange`

```
handleChange = e => {
   const { name, value } = e.target
   this.setState({
       [name]: value
   )}
  }
```

The way you call it in Child Component should be

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

see the code here
https://codesandbox.io/embed/unruffled-pascal-d5p2q?fontsize=14

For better structure, it`d be better if you put childComponent2 next to childComponent1. It only need total props.

Comment: No worries, just mark this question as answered if you solve it

Comment: The problem is still not solved. The handleChange function on the ParentComponent is still not getting triggered. Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-framework-cu0gb?fontsize=14

Comment: it's the way you call it in child component, see updated answer

Comment: You meant in ./components/ChildComponent2.jsx right? Still the same. I have place a console logging in the handleChange function and nothing gets printed in the console.

Comment: I still can see my change through the link I shared

Comment: Nicky. There seems to be a delay in rendering the value for the Total? The value coming in the text field is not correct.

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thank you so much. I now learned that we can use some sort of callback inside setState :)

Comment: Yes, that's because setState is asynchronous so we cant change total at the same time we change myArray. The callback guarantees that myArray updated before we count the total

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the `callback` immediately and not passing the `event` object. Try like this

```
onChange = {e => handleChange("total")(e)}
```

Also inside `handleChange` your argument's name is wrong

```
handleChange = propertyName => e => {
    this.setState({
        [property]: e.target.value
    });
}
```

Should be

```
handleChange = property => e => {
    this.setState({
        [property]: e.target.value
    });
}
```

Comment: I overlooked the argument name and I have already corrected it. I have modified my post above and tried to pass the event object as you said, but it's still not working. :( I added some console.log in the handleChange function but it's really not getting triggered.

Comment: Can you post a sandbox?

Comment: Wait! I got it to print the console.log in the handleChange when I manually changed the "total" text field. But what I want is to invoke the handleChange function even when the value in this "total" text field is updated automatically by some other logic in another component. Should I still use the onChange attribute for this?

Comment: here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-framework-cu0gb?fontsize=14 The handleChange function on ParentComponent.js is still not getting triggered.